# count in Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have many table:

GroupTableOne

```
id | name
1  | GroupTableOne
2  | GroupTableTwo
3  | GroupTableThree
4  | GroupTableFour
```

TableOne

```
id | group_table_one_id | name
1  | 1                  | tableOneOne
2  | 2                  | tableOneTwo
3  | 3                  | tableOneThree
4  | 4                  | tableOneFour
5  | 2                  | tableOneFive
6  | 2                  | tableOneSix
7  | 2                  | tableOneSeven
```

TableTwo

```
id | table_three_id | num | table_one_id
1  | 1              | 1   | 1          
2  | 1              | 1   | 2          
3  | 1              | 2   | 2          
4  | 2              | 2   | 3        
5  | 2              | 3   | 3         
6  | 3              | 3   | 2         
7  | 3              | 3   | 1
```

TableThree

```
id | num |  test
1  | 1   |  a
2  | 1   |  a
3  | 1   |  b
4  | 2   |  b
5  | 2   |  b
6  | 3   |  c
7  | 3   |  a
```

TableFour:

```
id | name
1  | dsfds
2  | sads
3  | asda
```

and if i will count all TableOne where test.ThreeTable = $id i have query in OneTableTable.class:

**this working OK.**

how can i count this same, but show count GroupTableOne instead of TableOne?

Now is counting for each name TableOne. I would like counting for each name GroupTableOne.

For example:

```
 name tableOne  | group   |  count
 tableOneOne    | 1       | 2
 tableOneTwo    | 2       | 2
 tableOneThree  | 3       | 1
 tableOneFour   | 4       | 4
 tableOneFive   | 2       | 3
 tableOneSix    | 2       | 1
 tableOneSeven  | 2       | 4
```

This is now, and **working OK.** I would like sum this for GroupTable*
for example for GroupTableTwo = tableOneTwo + tableOneFive + tableOneSix + tableOneSeven
:

```
name GroupTable  | count
GroupTableOne    | 2
GroupTableTwo    | 10
GroupTableThree  | 1
GroupTableFour   | 4
```

How can i modify my query for this? Better i would like new query. Thanks for help!

Comment: Heu... I don't really understand your problem... Could you explain more litteraly what you are trying to do and what do you need exactly? Do you want a SQL Request or a doctrine one as your title suggests. I don't understand how  you do your first count.

Comment: Please paste the code first.